# How do I get a random variant of an enum in GDScript, Godot 3.3?

Tags: random, enums, godot, gdscript

I have declared an enum like so in GDScript:

```
enum State = { STANDING, WALKING, RUNNING }
```

I want to get a random variant of this enum without mentioning all variants of it so that I can add more variants to the enum later without changing the code responsible for getting a random variant.

So far, I've tried this:

```
State.get(randi() % State.size())
```

And this:

```
State[randi() % State.size()]
```

Neither work. The former gives me Null, and the latter gives me the error "Invalid get index '2' (on base: 'Dictionary')."

How might I go about doing this in a way that actually works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be achieved the following way:

```
State.keys()[randi() % State.size()]
```

This works because `keys()` converts the State dictionary to an array, which can be indexed using `[]`.